# Weird behavior in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

In NodeJS, I was trying to read files in a directory and its subdirectories recursively

```
export const readDirRecursively = (rootDir) => {
  const files = [];

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Inner function for recursive operation
    function innerFun(dir) {
      fs.readdir(dir, (err, xpaths) => {
        if (err) reject(err);

        for (let xpath of xpaths) {
          const absPath = path.join(dir, xpath);
          if (fs.statSync(absPath).isDirectory()) {
            innerFun(absPath);
          } else {
            files.push(absPath);
          }
        }
      });
    }

    innerFun(rootDir);  // Call innerFun to initate
    console.log(files);   // contains vaules as expected
    console.log([...files]);  // empty array
    console.log(files.map(file => file + ' test')); // empty array

    const testVar = [1,2,3,4];
    console.log([...testVar]);    // This log [1,2,3,4] as expected

    resolve(files);
  });

};
```

And I found this unusual behavior with the array. Array `files` contains items as expected after recursive function is called. But when I try to `map` or copy with rest/spread operator or iterate over it, that array turns out empty.

I tried the same with `[1,2,3,4]` just to make sure. With it, everything works as expected. However, only `files` array shows this unusual behavior.

Comment: Your are using fs.readdir which is not synchronus you have to use fs. readdirSync - https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options

Comment: I am aware it is asynchronous and it is intended.  `console.log(files)` does log all files as expected so till this point, the function is working properly. The problem arises when I try to iterate over `files`

Comment: So it is asynchronous and recursive. No way to know when readdir will be finish. Even console.log(files) can show expected values because of it logs future form of files object. This means nothing. The only way is define innerFun like this:  function innerFun(dir) {
      var xpaths = fs.readdirSync(dir);
      for (let xpath of xpaths) {
        const absPath = path.join(dir, xpath);
        if (fs.statSync(absPath).isDirectory()) {
          innerFun(absPath);
        } else {
          files.push(absPath);
        }
      }
    }

Comment: Thanks! I get it finally. Didn't know the logs show future form of objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you log the array, are you then expanding it out in the console afterwards?

You've logged an array. Not a value, but an object. So when you go to view it, it shows you the values at the time you view it. But when you do `[...files]`, that's a new array constructed from the values of the old one (which there aren't any of yet) and this new array isn't modified by the asynchronous function so you just see that empty array.

Same for `files.map(...)` because that also returns a new array with no values.

And finally `testVar` doesn't change between the time you log it and the time you view the expanded object in your console.

When debugging objects, consider using `console.log(JSON.stringify(files))` to get a "snapshot" of it.

Comment: yeah I am expanding the logged array. `console.log(files)` does log all items as expected. But `console.log([...files])` or `files.map(...)` returns an empty array, (which is not expected) even when viewed expanded or `JSON.stringify`ed

Comment: Okay, I get it when you say I am viewing the object at the time I am seeing it not when it is actually logged. So, that means the logged array can change later too if it is mutated. Am I right?